# What is the best practice : Customer wants to publish app himself

Tags: iphone, ios

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS.

Customer wants to publish the application from his account.
So what is the best practice to avoid situations in case application is rejected from apple ?

I suppose, app should be submitted to app store by my own account with totally different account, icon, etc and will be removed from app store when it is published. So if the app is rejected I will fix the issues and resubmit (customer wont see this intermediate steps).

If yes, are there going to be any difficulties when the final(app with no potential rejections) app will be submitted by customer ? Any possible rejections by Apple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you have qa'd the app then you shouldn't be as worried about the app being rejected. if its rejected fix it and resubmit, and hope for the best.
2. All apps must have unique app names to be submited so if you were to use two accounts to submit you would have to use a fake name. Second off a fake name would be cause for rejection from apple in the first place because. apple would not look beyond the name in this case.
3. Content should be different if you submit the same app. As two different ones that will also be grounds for rejection.

Short version don't do this, just qa the app have the client approve it before submitting, once they approve it and you have as well if something unfortunate happens you both missed it.

Follow the other posters guidelines as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use any private (un-documented) functions.

Make sure the app does not crash.

Keep good track of memory management.

Do not stay in the main run loop too long. Use background threads for longer tasks.

Use ASYNC server requests to allow loading data in background.

and pray

Comment: I got a rejection last night, for using a selector in my method that had the same name as an undocumented selector. I used refactor and renamed it everywhere. Resubmitting today.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to submit app to app store with your account too? Use ad-hoc builds with your developer certificate to test it and to show to customer. When app is tested and ready build it for distribution with distribution certificate of customer (if he is ready to give it to you with private key etc.) I've made so and everything was fine. My customer wanted to build app itself and publish it, but struggled with Xcode and iTunes connect and just gave me access to his iTunes Connect page and developer page.